# PHP static:: vs $this in Late Static Bindings

Tags: php, inheritance, static, this, private

```
class ParentClass
{
    private function first(): void
    {
        p(__METHOD__);
    }

    public function test(): void
    {
        static::first();

        $this->first();

        $B = new B();
        $B->first();
    }
}

class B extends ParentClass
{
    public function first(): void
    {
        p(__METHOD__);
    }
}

$B = new B();
$B->test();
```

```
B::first

ParentClass::first

ParentClass::first
```

Why is it that having a reference to **B** in **$this** and having the public access modifier for the **first()** method, the method with the private modifier in **ParentClass** is called?
But if we allow inheritance by removing private, then the method from **B** will be called.

Doesn't this look illogical?

I expected that the **B::first()** method would be called at least for a direct call.
It may not be able to find **first()** in class **B** because it goes down the reverse inheritance chain, and this method in **B** does not override the first function from **ParentClass**.

Those. in order for it to be called from the scope of **ParentClass**, it must necessarily override the method and not just match the name.

Comment: `static::first()` works like `B::first()`, which explicitly calls `B`'s `first` without object context. For the other two cases, see the duplicate linked above, which should explain it.

Comment: @deceze arigatou